# How can I force resize the image without following the original scale?

Tags: php, download

I am going to grab some images from different websites and resize and the download them. I am using the following script:

```
        $img = file_get_contents($picarr[0]);

        $im = imagecreatefromstring($img);

        $width = imagesx($im);

        $height = imagesy($im);

        if($width > $height){    
            $newwidth = 600;
            $newheight = (600*$height)/$width;
        }else{   
            $newheight = 400;
            $newwidth = (400*$width)/$height;
        }

        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);

        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

        imagejpeg($thumb,'D:\mypic\9.jpg', 100); //save image as jpg

        imagedestroy($thumb); 

        imagedestroy($im);
```

this code is worked, but it seems it's following the original photo's scale (which is 4:3, and the size of original picture is 720 x 540). So the output is 600 x 450. How can I or is it possible to force resize the image to 600 x 400 ?

EDIT: Also, I am trying to add some watermark on the image.I know the way to add watermark when I submit the form, but how can I do this while running this script

Comment: it is possible, just programm a algorythmus to find out which scale ration is fitting to your needs (600 x 400) and then resize the picture with that scale ration and put the resized thumb in middle top left bottom what ever of the 600 x 400 px img

Comment: @donald123 What do you mean of middle top left bottom ?

Comment: expecting your rezige image have 580 x 320px and you want alway to get an image with 600 x 400, the background img you have to create (bg white) have 600 x 400 the rezized image came on the bg image and now you can choose, if the image will be placed left top, centered,or what ever